# ios AutoLayout : UIButton proportional sizing to screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, xcode7

My goal is for my buttons to adjust their **width** and **height** proportions according to different screen sizes.

My current screen width is **375px**, however, I want to make it compatible to a width of **320px**. I want to approach this by making the buttons' **width and height flexible**. I also want to maintain the  button's image aspect ratio.

I have following requirements..

1. Between buttons the margin is 4px.
2. Bottom margin is 20 px.
3. Buttons width should be resize according to screen width. And according to button's width height of the button should resize. So, I set aspect ratio of both the buttons.

I have added following constraints, plus SetAspect Ratios for both the buttons.
[image: I have added following constraints, plus SetAspect Ratios for both the buttons.]

Result comes like this.
[image: results come like this.]

**Now I am not using Stack View.**

Comment: so what did you try??? any constraints?

Comment: go for aspect ratio with leading and trailing margin.

Comment: I have added constraints to stack view for it's positioning, for button I have added no constraints.

Comment: Can you please tell us what constraints you have tried and for which all views?

Comment: I have not added any constraints, to buttons.

Comment: I would start with an aspect ratio constraint on one button don't set equal height/equal width constraints between the two buttons and set an aspect ratio constraint between the width of the first button and the root view width

Comment: you need to given two more constraint with this button leading and trailing spaces to the main view

Comment: @ArpitBParekh try using aspect ration and multipliers

Comment: Actually my view requirements are not clear, that I am working upon. Especially what behaviour it will take when changing the size of the screen.

Comment: I do not know how to use multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do to resolve this:

- add **leading** + **trailing** + **bottom** constraints to the stack view to
  allow it to have the variable width
- constrain your first button to use **leading** + **top** + **bottom** values of **0** to the stack view
- constrain your second button to use **trailing** + **top** + **bottom** values of **0** to the
  stack view
- add a **horizontal spacing** of **4px** between the buttons
- add **aspect ratio** constraints to each button
- add **equal widths** constraint on the buttons

Comment: Now, I am not using the stack view, but I mean what you said, adn mostly added the constraint like this. Please see , I have added the picture.

Comment: Did you add the equal widths constraint between the 2 buttons?  That should have kept them consistent.

Comment: No, I have not added yet.I will try it.